# PhpBB vs Jforum wrt customization

Tags: customization, forum, phpbb

People have been saying that JForum is easily customizable, and lots of other things in favor of JForum. Through this question, I want to know from those who have used both Jforum and phpbb, that how easy or difficult is customization of the forum in both of these.
For example, say you want to change the theme/template. In my experience I found it much easier to change theme in phpbb ( but still haven't found a way to change the theme in JForum). 
Please also suggest some resources where I can find some support for JForum, I couldn't find any support/documentation and so I'm still confused whether to switch to phpbb even if the client prefers Java?

To put this question another way, is there any reason why someone should use JForum when phpBB is available? (I hope it's not the same thing as Java vs Php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, 1 month and no answer! Looks like this question is not much important, perhaps because there aren't many who have used JForum and phpbb both.
After going through both of them, I eventually decided to go with phpbb given the customization possible, so my vote is towards phpbb. Opinions on this question are still welcome.